# Cardinal of a specific set

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

I was trying to prove that $${\rm card}\{ (k,n)\in\mathbb{N}^*\times\mathbb{N}; k(2n+1+k)=\text{ product of the first i prime numbers } \}=2^{i-1}.$$
Calculations for $2,2\times 3,2\times 3\times 5$ shows that this is true, but I am trying to prove it in general. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I meant N not Z (k  positive integer, n non-negative integer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of solutions $(k,n)$ is the number of pairs $(k,\ell)$ of integers $0<k<\ell$ such that $p_1\dots p_i=k\ell.$ (Such $k,\ell$ will obviously be of distinct parity since only one of them contains the factor $p_1=2.$) Equivalently, it is the number of positive divisors $k$ of $p_1\dots p_i$ such that $k<p_1\dots p_i/k.$ So, it is half the total number of positive divisors of this product, i.e. it is $2^i/2.$

Comment: Please strive not to post answers to PSQs. cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).